# Get specific property within an array of json objects

Tags: typescript, dictionary, pipe

this piece of code collects an array with multiple json object which contains an item with a code.

```
  itemcodes$ = this.product$
    .pipe(
      map((data) => data.items),
      filter((p) => Boolean(p))
    );
```

```json
[
   {
      "item1":{
         "code":"123"
      }
   },
   {
      "item2":{
         "code":"125"
      }
   },
]
```

How can extend this code so I  only collect the codes of the different items?
regards.

Comment: Did you solve this by any chance?